# XenServer alternative to VMWare VSA?

Tags: vmware, high-availability, xen, san

I have been looking at virtual storage appliances available for the VMware platform, transforming local storage to replicated storage. Such as VMWare VSA.
These still require an extended budget, all included

Any options for XenServer, allowing for live migration, fault tolerance, and high availability without using external SANs?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you would be so much better off using shared storage, even a NAS box or something. It will save you a lot of headaches, and time. I know that's not your question though!

Comment: Thanks and yes, I do see that this is the most supported way to go for XenServer. I was checking into DRBD but it is quite finicky. I had a look at GFS and ClusterGFS but then this is RedHat now and won't necessarily add simplicity to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution you find will complicate your environment and make your hosts unsupported. What you should be doing is using shared storage, period.

drbd isn't a great solution as it breaks when you want multiple nodes. There are some theoretical ways to do this but the problem becomes the more you change the XenServer system itself the more you open it to crash possibilities.

To answer your question more directly you can use a shared filesystem like GFS/lustre, etc, but you will still be spending a lot of time and energy to effectively make your systems unsupported and set up in an unstable way. Buy a NAS/SAN :)